# SailsJS API file upload

Tags: sails.js, postman

I am using a tutorial I found [here](http://maangalabs.com/blog/2014/08/12/uploading-a-file-in-sails/) to help me figure out file uploads in SailsJS. I have been able to get the uploads working when using the .ejs template engine in Sails, but I need the file uploads to work with the RESTapi. The URL I have setup is 'http://localhost:1337/file/upload', I am using Postman chrome app to to send a file to the server, but the response I get back is:

```
{
  "status": 200,
  "file": []
}
```

When not using the API (doing it within the .ejs template) I get the following response:

```
{
  "status": 200,
  "file": [
    {
      "fd": "path/to/uploaded/file/.tmp/uploads/assets/images/18c60ef7-b176-4375-8789-e0f80de29cea.pdf",
      "size": 48541,
      "type": "application/pdf",
      "filename": "file.pdf",
      "status": "bufferingOrWriting",
      "field": "uploadFile"
    }
  ]
}
```

I am not sure where the problem lies, am I not passing the file to the server? or is the server not dealing with the file correctly once it is received?

for reference, here is my controller code:

```
module.exports = {
    upload: function  (req, res) {
        if(req.method === 'GET')
            return res.json({'status':'GET not allowed'});                      

        var uploadFile = req.file('uploadFile');
        uploadFile.upload({ dirname: 'assets/images'},function onUploadComplete (err, files) {              
            if (err) return res.serverError(err);                               
            res.json({status:200,file:files});
        });
    },
};
```

Comment: at backend are you getting the file??beacuse i think you are not getting anyfile!console.log(uploadFile);

Comment: make sure if the uploadFile.fieldName!=='NOOP_file'!!!!
means it shoul be uploadFile.fieldName==='uploadFile'

Comment: Ok, I consoled out 'uploadFile' and I am getting 'fieldName: 'NOOP_uploadFile'', does this mean I am not passing the files to the server? Is this potentially a setting within Postman?

Comment: I have tried this again, some times I get 'fieldName: uploadFile' in the console, with a time out error returned: '{
  "code": "ETIMEOUT",
  "message": "ETIMEOUT: An Upstream (`uploadFile`) timed out waiting for file(s). No files were sent after waiting 10000ms."
}'  The rest of the time I get 'fieldName: 'NOOP_uploadFile'

Comment: postman is behaving weird i guess!

Comment: your postman is not sending the file thats why you can not recieve at back-end....please ensure if you are using post request and you have latest version of postman app!!

Comment: Solved, Postman was causing the issue. I upgraded and now it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the interests of closing this off so it might help somebody else, Postman was causing the problem - once i upgraded to the latest version everything worked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

i do the same way.for My case and it works;

```
  upload: function  (req, res) {
    if(req.method === 'GET')
      return res.negotiate(new Error('GET not allowed'));
    var fileName;
    try{
      fileName=req.file('uploadFile')._files[0].stream.headers['content-disposition'].split('"').reverse()[1];
    }
    catch(e){
      fileName="abc.abc";
    }
    req.file('uploadFile').upload({
      dirname:'../../tmp',
      saveAs:fileName
    },function onUploadComplete(err,files){
      if(err){
        console.log(err);
        return res.serverError(err);
      }
      if(!files.length) {
        return res.serverError(new Error('No file Uploaded'))
      }
      res.ok(files);
    });
  }
```

You can see this....
[image: So You can see that works for me]